# List of all needed OpenCV dlls by each EmguCV dll

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I am trying to locate dependencies of each EmguCv dll using a decompiler. However I don't want to miss anything because those OpenCv dlls maybe calling each other inside external calls.

Is there a list somewhere? I have tried EmguCV forums but I couldn't get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open it with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/):

> Scans 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module (exe, dll, ocx, sys, and others), and builds a hierarchical tree diagram of all dependent modules.

Comment: It works for OpenCv dlls but it doesn't seem to understand DLLImport calls in EmguCv dlls. Any idea about that?

Comment: Same question, because emgucv x86 dlls have a total of 396 MB!

Comment: It seems all OpenCV/EmguCV dll are required, did you find a way to reduce the size ? Previous version was only 16Mb and now it's 400mb !